# Access a web app from outside an Azure k8s

Tags: azure, kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-ingress

what is the best way to access a web app running in aks container from outside the cluster with a name, which is already defined in Azure DNS zone? and an external DNS server can be helpful for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would setup an [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) that would point to your service which exposes the web app.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: simple-fanout-example
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: your.web.app.address
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: service
          servicePort: 8080
```

> [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#ingress-v1beta1-networking-k8s-io)  exposes HTTP and HTTPS routes from outside the cluster to  [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)  within the cluster. Traffic routing is controlled by rules defined on the Ingress resource.

```
    internet
        |
   [ Ingress ]
   --|-----|--
   [ Services ]
```

> An Ingress may be configured to give Services externally-reachable URLs, load balance traffic, terminate SSL / TLS, and offer name based virtual hosting. An  [Ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers)  is responsible for fulfilling the Ingress, usually with a load balancer, though it may also configure your edge router or additional frontends to help handle the traffic.
>
> An Ingress does not expose arbitrary ports or protocols. Exposing services other than HTTP and HTTPS to the internet typically uses a service of type  [Service.Type=NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport)  or  [Service.Type=LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer).
>
> I would recommend reading [Create an ingress controller in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic), or use Azure Application Gateway as an ingress this is explained [here](https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/) and you can find tutorials on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress)